# When was the pagination of the Talmud begun and finalized and by whom?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara

Early editions of the Talmud did not have page numbers.  (Early commentators give citations to chapters.)  When did page numbering begin and, if today's page numbering differs, when was the page numbering finalized, and who established these page numbers?

Comment: Likely duplicate of [layout of the Gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10505/11501)

Comment: It hasn't been finalized. The modern Steinsaltz edition used a new pagination.

Comment: @DoubleAA I haven't seen that, yet. But, in a sense, Art Scroll also has different paginations. Although, in actuality, they do keep the Vilna version, but they may take 10 pages of English and commentary for one amud.

Answer (score 3):

The most commonly used pagination of the Talmud was printed by [Daniel Bomberg](http://Bomberg) in 1523:

> The Bomberg edition of the Talmud established the standard both in terms of page layout as well as pagination (with the exception of the tractate Berachot which follows Bomberg’s second edition). Prior to the printing of the Talmud, manuscripts had no standard page division, and the Talmud text usually did not appear on the same page as the commentaries, which were contained in separate codices. The standard page layout in use in all conventional editions of Talmud today (also the accepted method of citing a Talmudic reference) follows the pagination of Bomberg’s 1523 publication. ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Bomberg))